# App shows Image first then shows the animation

Tags: android, android-animation, fadein

The problem with my code is that it is showing the image first and then showing the animation(fade in).Firstly the image is shown on the screen for approx a second and then fading in of that same image occurs.Please help.
This is the code :

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

    private Animation translate;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);



        final ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        Animation translate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.translate);
        image.startAnimation(translate);

        final int[] imageArray = {R.drawable.agra, R.drawable.bang,
                R.drawable.mumbai
        };

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            int i = 0;

            public void run() {
                image.setImageResource(imageArray[i]);
                i++;
                if (i > imageArray.length - 1) {
                    i = 0;
                }
                handler.postDelayed(this, 4000);
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 4000);

    }




}
```

and this is the animation file translate.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="4000"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:fromAlpha="0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:repeatCount="-1"
    android:toAlpha="1">
</alpha>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your XML, set the image view to INVISIBLE:

```
<ImageView
     ....
     android:visibility:"invisible"/>
```

Then, try to update your code like below:

```
final ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
Animation translate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.translate);
translate.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        findViewById(R.id.image).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

    }
});

image.startAnimation(translate);
```

Comment: thanks for your quick answer but the problem persists